# Core Plot EXC_BAD_ACCESS during test on iPhone 6

Tags: ios, ios8, core-plot, iphone-6

I have set up a graph with core plot that show an animation when in the presence of new data to display. I followed the example code of CorePlot and situaizone is this:

- On iPhone 5 with iOS 8.1.2 everything works properly
- On iPad 4 with iOS 8.1.2 everything works properly
- On iPhone 6 with iOS 8.1.2 I have this error when I start the animation that changes the x and y axis of the graph.

This is the code block activated by the timer every second:

```
-(void)newData {

CPTGraph *graphTop = self.hostViewTop.hostedGraph;
CPTPlot *plotTop = [graphTop plotWithIdentifier:@"TWD"];

if (plotTop) {

    if (twdData.count > 3600) {
        NSRange range;
        range.location = 0;
        range.length = twdData.count-3600;
        [twdData removeObjectsInRange:range];
        [plotTop deleteDataInIndexRange:range];
    }

    thePlotSpaceTop = (CPTXYPlotSpace *)graphTop.defaultPlotSpace;
    NSUInteger location = (currentIndexTWD > twdDataRange ? currentIndexTWD - twdDataRange + 1 : 0);

    CPTPlotRange *newXRange = [CPTPlotRange plotRangeWithLocation:CPTDecimalFromUnsignedInteger(location)
                                                           length:CPTDecimalFromUnsignedInteger(twdDataRange)];

    [CPTAnimation animate:thePlotSpaceTop
                 property:@"xRange"
            fromPlotRange:thePlotSpaceTop.xRange
              toPlotRange:newXRange
                 duration:CPTFloat(0.1)];

    currentIndexTWD++;

    ...

    double avgTWD = 0.0;
    int maxTWD = ...
    int minTWD = ...

        CPTPlotRange *newYRange = [CPTPlotRange plotRangeWithLocation:CPTDecimalFromInt(minTWD) length:CPTDecimalFromInt((maxTWD-minTWD)+(maxTWD-minTWD)/3.5)];

        [CPTAnimation animate:thePlotSpaceTop
                     property:@"yRange"
                fromPlotRange:thePlotSpaceTop.yRange
                  toPlotRange:newYRange
                     duration:CPTFloat(0.2)];

        [CPTAnimation animate:((CPTXYAxisSet *) graphTop.axisSet).xAxis
                     property:@"orthogonalCoordinateDecimal"
                  fromDecimal:((CPTXYAxisSet *) graphTop.axisSet).xAxis.orthogonalCoordinateDecimal
                    toDecimal:CPTDecimalFromInt(minTWD) duration:CPTFloat(0.2)];

    }

    ((CPTScatterPlot *)plotTop).areaBaseValue = CPTDecimalFromInt(minTWD);

    NSNumber *newData;

    if ([plotTop cachedDataCount] > 50) {
        newData = [NSDecimalNumber numberWithDouble:[Utils randomBetweenMin:0 andMax:20]];
    } else if ([plotTop cachedDataCount] > 20) {
        newData = [NSDecimalNumber numberWithDouble:[Utils randomBetweenMin:2 andMax:12]];
    } else {
        newData = [NSDecimalNumber numberWithDouble:[Utils randomBetweenMin:minTWDVal andMax:maxTWDVal]];
    }

    int newTwdData = [newData intValue];

    ...

    [twdData addObject:[NSNumber numberWithInt:(int)calculatedTwd]];
    lastTwd = calculatedTwd;
    [plotTop insertDataAtIndex:twdData.count - 1 numberOfRecords:1];
    graphTop.title = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"TWD %d°     avg %d°", newTwdData, (int)avgTWD];

}
}
```

This is my error log:

```
Path:                /private/var/mobile/Containers/Bundle/Application/2E266FC1-3963-4AFB-890E-F6EFBDEC8AB9/ESA Instruments.app/ESA Instruments
Identifier:          com.astrayacht.ESA-Instruments
Version:             1.0 (1.0)
Code Type:           ARM-64 (Native)
Parent Process:      launchd [1]

Date/Time:           2015-01-09 15:35:50.512 +0100
Launch Time:         2015-01-09 15:35:44.833 +0100
OS Version:          iOS 8.1.2 (12B440)
Report Version:      105

Exception Type:  EXC_BAD_ACCESS (SIGSEGV)
Exception Subtype: KERN_INVALID_ADDRESS at 0x439c9ac4308870de
Triggered by Thread:  0

Thread 0 name:  Dispatch queue: com.apple.main-thread
Thread 0 Crashed:
0   libobjc.A.dylib                 0x000000019432bbdc objc_msgSend + 28
1   ESA Instruments                 0x000000010015a268 -[CPTXYPlotSpace setXRange:] + 192
2   ESA Instruments                 0x000000010018ca0c -[CPTAnimation update:] + 2088
3   Foundation                      0x0000000184a96e14 __NSFireTimer + 88
4   CoreFoundation                  0x0000000183b7a8d4 __CFRUNLOOP_IS_CALLING_OUT_TO_A_TIMER_CALLBACK_FUNCTION__ + 24
5   CoreFoundation                  0x0000000183b7a584 __CFRunLoopDoTimer + 884
6   CoreFoundation                  0x0000000183b77fd0 __CFRunLoopRun + 1368
7   CoreFoundation                  0x0000000183aa50a0 CFRunLoopRunSpecific + 392
8   GraphicsServices                0x000000018cc475a0 GSEventRunModal + 164
9   UIKit                           0x00000001883da3bc UIApplicationMain + 1484
10  ESA Instruments                 0x0000000100117a60 main (main.m:16)
11  libdyld.dylib                   0x0000000194986a04 start + 0

Thread 1 name:  Dispatch queue: com.apple.libdispatch-manager
Thread 1:
0   libsystem_kernel.dylib          0x0000000194a84c94 kevent64 + 8
1   libdispatch.dylib               0x000000019496c97c _dispatch_mgr_invoke + 272
2   libdispatch.dylib               0x000000019495f3b0 _dispatch_mgr_thread + 48

Thread 2:
0   libsystem_kernel.dylib          0x0000000194a9fc78 __workq_kernreturn + 8
1   libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x0000000194b39390 _pthread_wqthread + 988
2   libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x0000000194b38fa4 start_wqthread + 0

Thread 3:
0   libsystem_kernel.dylib          0x0000000194a9fc78 __workq_kernreturn + 8
1   libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x0000000194b39390 _pthread_wqthread + 988
2   libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x0000000194b38fa4 start_wqthread + 0

Thread 4:
0   libsystem_kernel.dylib          0x0000000194a9fc78 __workq_kernreturn + 8
1   libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x0000000194b39390 _pthread_wqthread + 988
2   libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x0000000194b38fa4 start_wqthread + 0

Thread 5:
0   libsystem_kernel.dylib          0x0000000194a9fc78 __workq_kernreturn + 8
1   libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x0000000194b39390 _pthread_wqthread + 988
2   libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x0000000194b38fa4 start_wqthread + 0

Thread 6:
0   libsystem_kernel.dylib          0x0000000194a84e7c mach_msg_trap + 8
1   libsystem_kernel.dylib          0x0000000194a84cf4 mach_msg + 68
2   CoreFoundation                  0x0000000183b79ecc __CFRunLoopServiceMachPort + 196
3   CoreFoundation                  0x0000000183b77e20 __CFRunLoopRun + 936
4   CoreFoundation                  0x0000000183aa50a0 CFRunLoopRunSpecific + 392
5   CoreFoundation                  0x0000000183af71f8 CFRunLoopRun + 108
6   CoreMotion                      0x00000001844a298c 0x184460000 + 272780
7   libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x0000000194b3be7c _pthread_body + 160
8   libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x0000000194b3bdd8 _pthread_start + 156
9   libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x0000000194b38fac thread_start + 0

Thread 7:
0   libsystem_kernel.dylib          0x0000000194a9fc78 __workq_kernreturn + 8
1   libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x0000000194b39390 _pthread_wqthread + 988
2   libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x0000000194b38fa4 start_wqthread + 0

Thread 0 crashed with ARM Thread State (64-bit):
    x0: 0x00000001985bc3c8   x1: 0x000000010019d10e   x2: 0x0000000174278d40   x3: 0x000000016fd714c8
    x4: 0x000000016fd71508   x5: 0x0000000000000001   x6: 0x3736363636312e30   x7: 0x0000000000000000
    x8: 0x000000010015a1a8   x9: 0x0000000100ad96c0  x10: 0x439c9ac42f00709e  x11: 0x459c88c4459c8ac4
   x12: 0x439c9ac4308870de  x13: 0x00ad960100ad96c0  x14: 0x0000000000000000  x15: 0x00000001742e5889
   x16: 0x000000019432bbc0  x17: 0x0000000000000000  x18: 0x0000000000000000  x19: 0x0000000174142890
   x20: 0x00000001985bc3c8  x21: 0x000000018e0f66b2  x22: 0x000000010019d10e  x23: 0x0000000000000005
   x24: 0x0000000174273200  x25: 0x0000000000000028  x26: 0x00000001001a11c6  x27: 0x0000000174056b30
   x28: 0x0000000188b4630c  fp: 0x000000016fd715b0   lr: 0x000000010015a26c
    sp: 0x000000016fd71560   pc: 0x000000019432bbdc cpsr: 0x20000000
```

Thanks in advance for the help

Comment: What version of Core Plot are you using? That looks like a bug that has been fixed in the latest code.

Comment: Was there ever a resolution for this?